# Couldn't get access token from azure auth using package "ad-b2c-react-native" Expo - React Native

Tags: react-native, azure-active-directory, expo, azure-ad-b2c

I am not getting access-token in response from azure auth in react native, following are my config,

```
<AuthProvider
        tenant={'<SomeTenant>'}
        appId={'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'}
        loginPolicy="<login-policy>"
        passwordResetPolicy="<password-reset-policy>"
        scope={'https://somedev.onmicrosoft.com/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/Access.All'}
        redirectURI={'msauth://org.myweb.somedev/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
>
```

I think the issue is with my scope, but tried different scopes options from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent and got the same response.

```
access: ""
error:null
expiresOn:0
id:""
isAuthentic:false
```

I am using `ad-b2c-react-native` package for azure auth, tried different packages like `react-native-azure-auth` but got issues regarding token.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C access token scopes are [mostly custom API permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens#scopes). The documentation you refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent is for Azure AD which, although similar, differs in many aspects such as the number of built-in resources (apis) and scopes available.